# Flutter Podfile issue

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, podfile

Recently I've update the Xcode 15 and IOS 17, and I'm facing error "DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR" and code signing issue in my Xcode.

I need to combine these 2 into my post_install section, but each time I put them together, I will encounter 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

I'm new to Podfile and do not know how to debug, how am I going to combine these 2 section of code?

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
      xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
      xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
      File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
     end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
        xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
        File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
  end
end
```

--

```
flutter clean
```

go to ios folder

```
 cd ios
```

delete Podfile.lock

```
rm Podfile.lock
```

delete Pods folder as well

```
rm -rf Pods/
```

install packages

```
flutter pub get
```

install pod

```
pod install
```